# how can I make my image more visible on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have used bootstrap for the layout, however when you view this page on a mobile device the overlaid text seems to hide most of the image, I have tried a couple of different things like media queries.

I have also added in some media queries for the website in general, which has helped the text to stay in the box but still is covering a large majority of the image.

```css
/* CONTACT Page */

.somesection {
  margin-top: 50px!important;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: raleway;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.overlay-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  /*important*/
  bottom: 21vw;
  /*important*/
  padding: 25px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}


/*responsive */


   
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* For mobile phones: */

[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content inset">
  <div class="row">





    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <hr>




        <div class="container somesection">
          <div class="row col-xs-8">
            <img align="left" src="images/contact.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-offset-4 overlay-text">
            <h1>CONTACT STEPHANIE</h1>
            <br>
            <p>If you have any questions or any design requests please email me at:</p>


            <h3><i>EMAIL</i></h3>



          </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

/* CONTACT Page */

```
.somesection {
  margin-top: 50px!important;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: raleway;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```
<div class="page-content inset">

        <hr>




        <div class="container somesection">
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8 col-sm-8">
            <img align="left" src="images/contact.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
            <h1>CONTACT STEPHANIE</h1>
            <br>
            <p>If you have any questions or any design requests please email me at:</p>


            <h3><i>EMAIL</i></h3>



          </div>

        </div>
```

Try this will solve your problem!

Comment: the only thing is that the text now does not overlay the image ?

Comment: @stephcatterall I didn't understand what else do you want? Please explain ?

Comment: Sorry @nour I want to have an image where text overlays on the right in a grey box, which works fine on desktop with the code I have. However when you view the webpage on a phone the box covers most of the image and not sure how to move the image or make an adjustment to change this